# Need assist with JUnit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm brand new to JUnit so I'm having a bit of trouble. I'm currently running JUint 4, and I'm trying to write a test that is specifically supposed to fail, yet it keeps passing as successful. I need your help, as I feel I'm writing these correctly, yet they're not working as intended. Here's my main class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class PrimeNumbers implements Iterable<Integer> {
    private List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    /*
     * creates a list of n prime numbers
     *
     * @param n - the number of primes to compute silently treats negative
     * arguments as zero
     */
    public void computePrimes(int n) {
        int count = 1; // count of primes
        int number = 2; // number tested for primeness
        boolean isPrime; // is this number a prime

        while (count <= n) {
            isPrime = true;
            for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= number / 2; divisor++) {
                if (number % divisor == 0) {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break; // for loop
                }
            }
            if (isPrime && (number % 10 != 9)) { // THIS IS THE FAULT!!!
                primes.add(number);
                count++;
            }
            number++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return primes.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return primes.toString();
    }

}
```

and here's my test class:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class PrimeNumbersTest {

    @Test
    public void test(){
        //instantiate prime object, create primes list, and iterator
        PrimeNumbers prime = new PrimeNumbers();
        List<Integer> primeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        //array holding 19 so I can compare the objects
        int[] primeArray = new int[]{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19};
        int i = 0;
        int n = 8;
        //call the method
        prime.computePrimes(n);
        Iterator<Integer> primeIterator = primeList.iterator();
        //loop to iterate through the list and then check last item if it is equal to 19
        while(primeIterator.hasNext()){
            if(!(primeIterator.equals(primeArray[i]))) {
                assertTrue("incorrect", primeIterator.equals(primeArray[i]));
            }
            i++;
            primeIterator.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks guys for the help!

Comment: Nothing is telling the test to fail explicitly, are you sure that the code being executed does indeed execute the line that includes  `assertTrue("incorrect", primeIterator.equals(primeArray[i]));` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at these two lines:

```
List<Integer> primeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
...
Iterator<Integer> primeIterator = primeList.iterator();
```

You create an empty list and then test the contents of *that* list. Since there's nothing in that list your code never enters the `while` loop and hence the test assertion is never invoked.

If you replace this ...

```
Iterator<Integer> primeIterator = primeList.iterator();
```

... with this ...

```
Iterator<Integer> primeIterator = prime.iterator();
```

... then you'll be testing the iterator created by your `PrimeNumbers` class. This must be what you want to do though it should be noted that this invocation will always return false: `primeIterator.equals(primeArray[i])` (since it is comparing the iterator, rather than a value inside the iterator, against the 'expected' array) so your test will fail on its first iteration over the while loop. This would be a false negative.

It looks like you are trying to prove that `PrimeNumbers` (which has been coded to *not* return 19) does not return 19 when it is asked to return the first 8 prime numbers. If so, then the following might be a more compact - and specific - way to do that:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    //instantiate prime object, create primes list, and iterator
    PrimeNumbers prime = new PrimeNumbers();

    int n = 8;
    int unexpectedPrimeNumber = 19;

    // call the method
    prime.computePrimes(n);

    // gather the generated prime numbers into a list for easier assertion
    List<Integer> primeList = new ArrayList<>();
    prime.iterator().forEachRemaining(integer -> primeList.add(integer));

    assertEquals("Should contain " + n + " prime numbers!", n, primeList.size());
    assertFalse("Should not contain the unexpected prime number: " + unexpectedPrimeNumber, primeList.contains(unexpectedPrimeNumber));
}
```